# Wi-Fi interference and loss of SSIDs in scans

Tags: wireless-networking, interference

I know that wireless signals can interfere with each other, and other devices like cordless phones, microwave ovens, and others can cause interference also. What I am mostly wondering is when you see such interference and bring up a Wi-Fi analyzer on an Android device ([This app to be more precise](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.farproc.wifi.analyzer)) then some channels will be completely void of any SSID. That is, the device doesn’t see any SSIDs on the channels affected by the interference.

I would have thought that the SSID would show up, but that the device would not connect to a certain SSID because there was another signal towering above it causing interference.

Mainly what causes me confusion is that when there are multiple SSID's using the same channel, then the Wifi Analyzer sees all these SSID's, but if there is a signal that doesn't broadcast an SSID and is causing interference then the app doesn’t show any SSIDs at all.

My main question is, why does the Wi-Fi Analyzer not see the SSIDs when there is any interference that does not have an SSID (like a phone, microwave, etc.) but it sees all the SSIDs if the interference is other Wi-Fi signals. I am pretty sure the access point is sending out its SSID: I only have to tell it to go to another channel and voilà, it’s there for every Wi-Fi capable device to pick up its SSID.

Comment: I honestly can't follow your question. If your question is whether a WiFi analyzer can see interference from non-WiFi sources, the answer is no. You need a WiFi spectrum analyzer for that.

Comment: This is all very common and can't really cause interference, just congestion.

Comment: If the SSID is not broadcast then how can the app display it? It has nothing to display if it is not broadcast.

Comment: See edit that hopefully articulated the question a bit better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, non-Wi-Fi RF energy on a channel can interfere enough to cause Wi-Fi scans of that channel to fail to return any results. There are several ways this can happen:

- It may be that the client doing the scan saw too much RF power on the channel and decided it was in use and it shouldn't transmit any Probe Requests.
- It may be that the APs on that channel couldn't successfully receive the client's Probe Requests because of the interference.
- It may be that the APs on that channel saw too much RF power on the channel and decided it was in use and they shouldn't transmit any Probe Responses or Beacons.
- It may be that the client couldn't successfully receive the APs Probe Requests or Beacons because of the interference.
- It may be that all the APs in the area were set for automatic channel selection, and they all avoided the channel with the interference, so there truly aren't any Wi-Fi networks on the channel(s) being blasted by non-Wi-Fi RF energy.

Bear in mind that tools like inSSIDer that plot which SSIDs cover which channels/frequencies at which power levels are designed to LOOK like RF spectrum analyzers, but they are not true RF spectrum analyzers. They take normal Wi-Fi network scan results lists and plot them. They are not capable of detecting or plotting non-Wi-Fi energy, so they'll never show the interference from microwave ovens, cordless phones, baby monitors, or any other non-Wi-Fi device that uses the 2.4GHz or 5GHz bands.

Comment: Thank you Spiff for those points of possible causes to this loss of SSID's. I am leaning towards either point 1 or 4 since the SSID of the AP did not show up on any other channel (and it was set to automatic channel selection so if it had jumped to another channel then it would have shown up in wifi-analyzer). This is a Thomson Media Gateway router with inbuilt wifi and if the wifi is active there is a green light on front showing that. In this case the green light was active and blinking (showing traffic). That further suggests point 1 or 4 are the culprits.